# Build a string from structured folder - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to build a method or function that can rebuild the names of sql scripts according to their hierarchy and hold them in a new list

I will take this ZIP file that holds 2 sql files (could be many), create a temp folder with subfolder and extract this files into it and search only for sqls.

```
$file = "C:\patch-8.6.22.0 (1309041+1301513 +1326286 +1344064 + 1423182 + 1420074).zip"

$tempFolder = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) (New-GUID).ToString('n')
New-Item -Path $tempFolder -ItemType Directory -Force 1>$Null

$subTemp = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath ([datetime]::Now.Ticks) 
& ${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe x $file "-o$($subTemp)" -y >$Null
$sqls = (Get-ChildItem $subTemp -Include "*.sql" -Recurse) | Sort-Object Name

foreach ($sql in $sqls) {
    write-host $sql
}

C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\c5561501831c43cea5598ddb2cb1efd5\638158002382341059\Patches\IDUDatabase\Default Data\Domain\Changes\02012019-V7-AddFlagOfNewCustomer.sql
C:\Users\Bandit\AppData\Local\Temp\c5561501831c43cea5598ddb2cb1efd5\638158002382341059\Patches\IDUDatabase\Default Data\Common\Configuration-data.sql
```

The goal is to create a new list that holds the names of the sqls + all the subfolders till the IDUDatabase, Besides IDUDatabase could be more subfolders like CollectorDadabase, ProbeDatabase and more
The method should search for one of the names (IDUDatabase,ProbeDatabase,..) and rebuild the name as I explained below. (I guess I need to add them as hardcoded)

Its should be like:

```
$Newsql
foreach ($sql in $Newsqls) {
    write-host $sql
}
Default Data\Domain\Changes\02012019-V7-AddFlagOfNewCustomer.sql
Default Data\Common\Configuration-data.sql

$newsqls = @()                       
foreach ($sql in $sqls) {
   $dllpath = Convert-Path($sql.PSPath)
   $ParentCount = ($dllpath.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)).count 
   for ($i = -1; $i -gt - $ParentCount; $i--) {
    $parentname = $dllpath.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[$i]
    write-host $parentname 
    if ($parentname -match 'IDUDatabase' -or $parentname -match 'ProbeDataBase') {
        $j = $i + 1
        break 
        }
    }
    $newsql = ""
    for ($i = $j ; $i -le -1 ; $i++) {
        $parentname = $dllpath.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[$i]
        $newsql +=  "\" + $parentname
        }
        $newsql = $newsql.TrimStart('\')
        $newsqls += $newsql
    }
```

Comment: What most people do is to add to the template something like %DATE% and then replace the %DATE% with a real date.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Create template files that look like this : Default Data\Domain\Changes\%DATE%-V7-AddFlagOfNewCustomer.sql.  Then have your script modify the file with a real date.

Comment: It was only an example for file... it could be any name

Comment: You want to replace string in files.  To make it easy to do replacement you can add %PLACE HOLDERS% for as many items that you need.

Comment: No need to respond, I managed to implement by my self 